# Using contents of ArrayList to draw a frame

Tags: android, opengl-es, if-statement, arraylist, ondraw

So I have this array list that is populated using a csv file. Once it is populated it is used to draw objects to frame. Here is my onDrawFrame method (i know its messy i'll clean up later)

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |
            GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glScalef(screenWidth/10, screenHeight/7, 0);

    while (currentLoadSpace < totalMapSize){

        loadObject = levelDat.get(currentLoadSpace);

        Log.d(TAG,"currentLoadSpace " + String.valueOf(currentLoadSpace));
        Log.d(TAG,"totalMapSize " + String.valueOf(totalMapSize));
        Log.d(TAG,"loadObject " + String.valueOf(loadObject));
        Log.d(TAG,"x " + String.valueOf(x));
        Log.d(TAG,"y " + String.valueOf(y));

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);

        if (String.valueOf(loadObject) == "000"){
            Log.d(TAG, "Empty Space");
        }

        if (String.valueOf(loadObject) == "001"){
            square.draw(gl);
            Log.d(TAG, "draw a square");
        }

        gl.glPopMatrix();
        currentLoadSpace++;
        updateXY();
    }

  currentLoadSpace = 0;
}
```

Basically what this code does is check to see whether the index of the value we are trying to read is less than the total size of the ArrayList. It then reads that value and checks it against the if statements (if the value is 000 then it won't draw anything but if the value is 001 then it will draw a square at location x, y) it repeats this for every value in the array list .

My problem is that the if statements aren't triggering. those log tags above them return all the values they should and load object always returns either a 000 or a 001 but I never get the log tags from within the if statements returned and my screen remains blank.

Here is the log from one loop of this code.

```
10-22 11:54:37.821: DEBUG/input(14680): currentLoadSpace 0
10-22 11:54:37.821: DEBUG/input(14680): totalMapSize 55
10-22 11:54:37.821: DEBUG/input(14680): loadObject 001
10-22 11:54:37.821: DEBUG/input(14680): x 0.0
10-22 11:54:37.821: DEBUG/input(14680): y 1.0
```

notice no square drawn log is returned so how come my if statements aren't recognizing the loadObject value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jack, Strings should NEVER be compared using the == operator.
This is how you should use it:

```
String.valueOf(loadObject).equalsIgnoreCase("001")
```

Comment: he he :) even the best developers occasionally make this silly mistake